# Nancy support for .NETCoreApp

Tags: asp.net-core, nancy

Trying to add the Nancy package to a new project. In project.json (dependencies segment) red squigly under "Nancy": "1.4.3". Mouseover displays an error relating to support for .NETCoreApp

[image: Nancy .NETCoreApp project.json error]

Comment: Nancy 1.4.3 only  supports framework 4.x Simple solution but suggest for experimental use only is to install what is, as of today, an alpha version:

Install-Package Nancy -Pre

Comment: UPDATE: Spoke too soon. Nancy 2.0.0-alpha doesn't work either so I guess we'll have to wait for Nancy to catch up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch of Nancy on github already runs on .net core.We are moving from Rake to Cake for the build script , hoping to wrap that up this week so .netcore support can be pushed to Nuget.So yes wait just a bit.

Comment: That's great. Not a blocker for me but I was feeling really bad for Christian Horsdal. In his new book "Microservices in .NET: with C#" he raves about Nancy and has it as a foundation in all his source.

Comment: Sifico, are there any news about Nancy builds? I tried similar configuration on my machine and receive the same error.
(Installing Nancy with "Install-Package Nancy")

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy/2.0.0-clinteastwood , please note .net core is only on 2.0-* packages.

Answer (score 1):

This example was original written on Stack Overflow Documentation:

#### Setup Nancyfx with Dotnet core v1.1, Kestrel, and Visual Studio Code on *nix systems

Prerequiste steps:

1. Get dotnet core for your platform:
   [Dotnet Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core)
2. Follow instructions and make sure dotnet core is working
3. Get Visual Studio Code for your platform:
   [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)
4. Launch Visual Studio Code (VS code) and install the C# extension then reload

#### Create self hosted NancyFx project:

1. Setup a project with a correct project directory structure.
   Open Bash Terminal and type:

   ```
   mkdir nancydotnetcore
   cd nancydotnetcore
   mkdir src 
   mkdir test
   touch global.json
   ```
2. Open global.json and enter the following code:

   ```
   {
       "projects":["src", "test"]
   }
   ```
3. In Bash terminal:

   ```
   cd src 
   mkdir NancyProject1
   dotnet new
   ```

   Open folder NancyProject1 in VS code
   You will get a warning: "Required assets to build and debug are missing from 'nancyproject1'."
   Click "Yes"
   Also you will see: There are unresolved dependencies from 'project.json'. Please execute the restore command to continue.
   Click "Close" we will get to this soon.
4. Add the dependencies, open "project.json" and overwrite it with the following:

   ```
   {
       "version": "1.0.0-*",
       "buildOptions": {
           "debugType": "portable",
           "emitEntryPoint": true
       },

       "frameworks": {
           "netcoreapp1.1": {
               "dependencies": {
                   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.1.0",
                   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
                   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.1.0",
                   "Nancy": "2.0.0-barneyrubble",
                   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                       "type": "platform",
                       "version": "1.1.0"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   VS code will ask to restore click "Restore"
5. Create folder "Modules" in VSCode project
   In the Modules folder add a file named "IndexModule.cs" then copy and save the following:

   ```
   namespace NancyProject1
   {
       using Nancy;
       public class IndexModule : NancyModule
       {
           public IndexModule()
           {
               Get("/", _ => "Hello dotnet core world!");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. In the root directory of the project create a file called "Startup.cs" and copy and paste the following:

   ```
   namespace NancyProject1
   {
       using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
       using Nancy.Owin;

       public class Startup
       {
           public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
           {
               app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Open file "Program.cs" and overwrite the content with the following and save:

   ```
   namespace NancyProject1
   {
       using System.IO;
       using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
       using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                   .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .UseKestrel()
                   .UseStartup()
                   .Build();

               host.Run();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
8. Done! Now lets run this and see the output.
   Click the debug symbol in VS Code, and Click the run button. It should compile and start the project.
   Open the browser @ http://localhost:5000
9. Pat yourself on the back and enjoy!

---

still pre release version but works with .net core as the time of this writing, view engines are very limited on core.

Comment: similarly can I host windows service using Nancy and .net core?

Answer (score 0):

Install-Package Nancy -Version 2.0.0-barneyrubble -Pre